# How can one close a Mahalo account?

Tags: account-management

How can one close (or perhaps maximally disable) a Mahalo user account?  There appear to be no provisions at all for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://techcrunch.com/2010/06/11/mahalo-facebook-calacanis/), you can email them with your request.  A feature to do it within the UI yourself is mentioned to be coming...well, weeks ago.